# SharePoint connector for worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there way to access MS share-point using IBM Worklight ?Any specific adapter available for this ?. I wanted find out what is the best way to connect to MS share-point using IBM WORKLIGHT. Is cast iron adapter suitable for this ?.